# Why does copy of the List still change properties in the original List using C#

Tags: c#, .net, properties, deep-copy, shallow-copy

Lets say I have this class

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
    List<Employee> Employees = new List<Employee>();
    Employees.Add(new Employee { FirstName = "firstname", LastName = "lastname", isActive = true });
    List<Employee> EmployeesCopy = new List<Employee>(Employees);
    EmployeesCopy[0].isActive = false;
```

Why does change in `isActive` property of `EmployeesCopy` also modify property in the original list?

Comment: Because `Employee` is a reference type(class).

Comment: Time to go back to the books so that you clearly understand the difference between reference and value types. This sh*t is **really** important. Make sure you get it.

Comment: may be this will help you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76153/Six-important-NET-concepts-Stack-heap-value-types

Comment: Yes, it is not and employee copy, but just another list containing the same employee.

Comment: This is a very well asked (but duplicate) question. It doesn't deserve a downvote. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the new list still contains references to the same employee objects. You can create new ones in a new list by doing something like this:

```
    List<Employee> Employees = new List<Employee>();
    Employees.Add(new Employee { FirstName = "firstname", LastName = "lastname", isActive = true });
    List<Employee> EmployeesCopy = Employees.Select(x => new Employee(x)).ToList();

    public class Employee
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public bool isActive { get; set; }

        public Employee()
        { }

        public Employee(Employee e)
        {
            FirstName = e.FirstName;
            LastName = e.LastName;
            isActive = e.isActive;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would better if `Employee` implemented [`IClonable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx).

Comment: Well, I think in this level, a copy constructor will be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a shallow copy, not a deep copy. This means that the new list contains the same objects from the original list.

To do a deep copy, you will need to iterate through your original list and make new `Employee` objects for the new list, like this.

```
private List<Employee> CloneEmployees(List<Employee> original)
{
    var newList = new List<Employee>();
    foreach (var employee in original)
    {
        newList.Add(new Employee 
            { 
                FirstName = employee.FirstName, 
                LastName = employee.LastName, 
                isActive = employee.isActive 
            });
    }
    return newList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why does change in the isActive property of EmployeesCopy also modify
>   the original list?|

Because both the list point to the same instance of the Employee object. You need to [deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically) your Employee object as well.

Answer (score 0):

The copy is a new `List` object, but it contains references to the same set of `Employee` objects that are in the original list. If you want the `Employee` objects in the two lists to be independent, then you have to copy them individually and put the copies into a new list.

Answer (score 0):

The copy you create is just a copy of the list. Not a copy of the objects. In other words, `Employees[0] == EmployeesCopy[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

because by using `new List<Employee>(Employees);` will give you the new instance of List but not the objects contained in the list. You should consider cloning of objects contained in the list also , use Binary Serialization to serialize object graph.